# I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket that I want to host as a static website

Tags: web, static, cloud, bucket

I've gone through all thousand steps and I still can't see the web content from a browser.  The troubleshooting page just sends me back to all the steps to set it up.  Is there a way I can actually debug this?

When I hit my url I just get:

**This site can’t be reached
Check if there is a typo in [www.takashinew.com](http://www.takashinew.com).
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN **

What does this mean exactly?

I tried going to chrome://net-internals/#dns and clearing the host cache, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Moved my hosting and domain back to my old provider (pair.com).  When I asked how to set up SSL, they replied how by email, took me 5min, and cost me nothing.